# NA/NaN values in bnlearn package R

Tags: r, null, nan, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I am using the `bnlearn` package in R to handle large amounts of data in `Bayesian networks`. The variables are discrete and have more than 3 million observations. 
With `bn.fit` function I could easily get the conditional probability distribution. However, some variables have unobserved values ​​(i.e., NA or NaN).

In some tests, I've got this:

```
nw.fit <-bn.fit (nw, date, method = 'bayes') 

Error in check.data (date): the data set contains NULL/NaN/NA values​​.
```

So, 
how could I deal with the data and get the conditional probability distribution?

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample of your data.. Also let us know whether you want to remove NA or you would like to continue with NAs...?

Comment: Some data structures in R support the `na.omit()` function. But you have not seen fit to give us anything we can use to determine what you are working with.

Comment: @BondedDust - Thats why I also asked Alex to tell us whether NA should be removed or keep as it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the catnet package can deal with missing data and is designed for discrete data

you can get conditional probabilities using cnProb(bnet,which)

here is an example

```
rm(list=ls())

### generate random data (not simply independent binomials)
set.seed(123)
n.obs <- 10
a1 <- rbinom(n.obs,1,.3)
a2 <- runif(n.obs)
a3 <- floor(-3*log(.25+3*a2/4))
a3[a3>=2] <- NA
a2 <- floor(2*a2)
my.data <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3 )
### discretize data into proper categories
my.data <- cnDiscretize(my.data,numCategories=2)

my.data
##    a1 a2 a3
## 1   1  2  1
## 2   2  1  2
## 3   1  2  1
## 4   2  2  2
## 5   2  1 NA
## 6   1  2  1
## 7   1  1 NA
## 8   2  1 NA
## 9   1  1 NA
## 10  1  2  1

## say we want a2 conditional on a1,a3

## first generate a network with a1,a3 ->a2
cnet <- cnNew(
          nodes = c("a1", "a2", "a3"),
          cats = list(c("1","2"), c("1","2"), c("1","2")),
          parents = list(NULL, c(1,3), NULL)
          )


## set the empirical probabilities from data=my.data
cnet2 <- cnSetProb(cnet,data=my.data)

## to get the conditional probability table
cnProb(cnet2,which='a2')

##$a2
##         a1        a3         0         1
## A 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
## B 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.5712826 0.4287174
## A 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
## B 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.5685786 0.4314214
```

Comment: Can't recreate your output here. Can you advise? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112535/na-nan-values-in-bnlearn-package-r

Answer (score 0):

Some variables have almost 1 million of unobserved values. This is a lot to just delete them. So I would like to continue with NAs.
Below have a little example of the data

```
 A  B   C   D   E   F   G
 1  1   2   2   NA  2   1
 0  1   2   2   1   3   3
 1  3   1   1   NA  2   2
 0  3   1   1   1   2   1
 0  4   1   1   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

As per what the owner of bnlearn: Marco Scutari has mentioned [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/NA-NaN-values-in-bnlearn-package-R-td4691894.html), the solution seems to be to do EM imputation for missing values.

As @pes has pointed above, catnet is a package that can be used, if all your variables are categorical.

The third alternative is to remove the rows with missing values or to pad them or use spline techniques (another family of MV imputations).